# How can I play a native ios Keyboard Touch sound with React-Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

**The Question**

I have a custom keyboard set up (it's a score tracker for a dart game app). What I'm missing is how can I play the iOS sounds like when you write a message in iMessages for example?

I could not find any help for this question what so ever. 
Not in the docs.

Do I really have to use this "early alpha" package "react-native-sounds" => Download this touch sound somewhere and play that sound onPress? Does `react-native` not provide this, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, react native doesn't provide such feature out of the box. You'll have to use [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound) or [react-native-audio-toolkit](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-audio-toolkit). I would go with the first one, it should do just fine for your use case